# Bug in Tidy in Snippet

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, stack-snippets

In simple words, when there's a code like this:

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/PreviousArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet.png" alt="PreviousArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet" width="50" height="50" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-161" />
```

The Stack Snippet Tidy feature makes it this way:

```html
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/PreviousArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet.png" alt="PreviousArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet" width="50" height="50" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-161"
/>
```

The bug is that, it should not bring down the `/>` making it to the next line. I have taken the exact specimen to demonstrate. It is still unclear that it is a margin (maximum columns or characters in a line) limitation or it is a bug.

Comment: It seems an attempt to avoid very long lines. If you write `a a a a a a `... repeated lots of times, it will be broken into multiple lines of same length.

Comment: @Oriol I guessed the same buddy. But this doesn't happen in the official code mirror.